# Webinstaller VS 2015 + Proxy + Admin account

Tags: visual-studio, proxy, windows-installer, installation, admin

my question is regarding the webinstaller by Microsoft f.e. Visual Studio 2015 SP 3.

If I start the Webinstaller I have to enter an admin account. But this account has no access to the Internet. Is it possible to start the webinstaller with a proxy Registration (user/passwd/Proxy URL ) ?

I need to download the data files via "normal" account and to install with an "admin" account. 
Does anyone have a solution ? - To download iso files is not a solution in my case because Microsoft will not offer iso files for VS 2017, I need a general solution.